# Is this a sufficient proof for "For all $k \in\Bbb R$, if $k$ is odd, then $4k + 7$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can I just say 4k is obviously even and even + odd is always odd, so odd?

Or is that too simple, am I missing something?

Comment: You can say as much, yeah. You could also just show that $4k$ is even by showing it's divisible by $2$, that's fine too. Or you could show it by induction maybe? Not sure, just a thought. It just all really depends on the level of formality you're expected to show and the context as well. Though note: the notion of being "even" or "odd" doesn't make sense for non-integer numbers (you said real numbers in the title). At least in any context I'm aware of.

Comment: Oh shoot you're right, so if it says "k is odd" is it just implying it's an odd integer?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what's being implied!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its simple like that. But if you are making a test or something like that you have to be sure that you can use the fact that "even+odd is odd" without proving it... otherwise just prove it! (Not so difficult)

Comment: Is it just using the "for some integer $j$, $k = 2j + 1$" ?

Comment: Yes, you have to get that "for some integer $j$, $k=2j+1$"... for this you just manipulate the equation like : $4k+7=2(2k+3)+1$ so in this case $j=2k+3$... like people said this question just make sense if $k\in \Bbb{Z}$